# Їмость чи попадя?

Tags: значення-слів

Завжди думула, що *імость* чи *Їмость* — це український відповідник російського слова *матушка*, *попадья*, тобто дружина священика. [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%87%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) дає визначення цього терміну, як дружина українського греко-католицького священика. Але в тлумачному словнику української мови я не зустріла такого слова. Натомість є слово [*попадя*](http://sum.in.ua/s/popadja).

Чи має слово *імость* чи *їмость* право на існування в українській мові?

Comment: Вкажіть, буль ласка, як правильно називати дружину православного священика? Бо в нас, на Франківщині, слова "матушка", "попадя" вживають тільки до дружини священника російського підпорядкування.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Натомість на [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/p/panimatka/38-1-0-11739) у розділі *Словник синонімів* знаходжу словникову статтю з іншою лексемою, де згадується "попадя":

> ПАНІМАТКА
>
> Синоніми до слова ПАНІМАТКА: мати, господиня ; ц. **попадя**; зв. ПАНІ; паньматка.

Отож паніматка = попадя. Лексеми ж "їмость" там не подають.

Проте **сучасний [Словник української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=202887&page=1255)** *містить (!)* таку статтю:

> **Ї́МОСТЬ**, Ї́МОСЦЬ, і, ж., зах.Дружина священика.
>
> За священиків молімось, За дяків, чернецтво, їмость
>   (В. Багірова)

Зауважу, що у Словнику української мови 1970-1980рр подається таке значення іменника піп:

> ПІП, попа, чол., розм. Духовне звання ***у православній церкві***, середнє між єпископом і дияконом.
>
> [Палажка:] Чом же ти у попи не постригся, коли в тебе мати попадя була? (Панас Мирний, V, 1955, 228);

Таким чином термін "попадя" є похідним від терміна "піп". Якщо ж ми говоримо про греко-католицьку церкву,то тут на означення священика є або власне термін "священик", або "панотець". Ані в того, ані в іншого дружину "попадею" не називали, лише "їмостю".

Отже, використання терміну "їмость" практикується, особливо у греко-католицькій церкві.

Comment: Додам, що «їмость» у СУМ-20 має помітку «зах» (можливо, «західноукраїнське», хоча я не знаю точно, як у них «зах» розшифровується).